# Div with 4 columns in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap , so that the form is responsive in all devices. I have added the bootstrap css and bootstrap js. 
I am trying to have a 4 column div structure, but the data is coming 2 rows. I have used the below code.

```
var formTable = "".concat("<div class='container' width='100%'><h2>Raise a New Request</h2><hr/>",
                                      "<br/>",
                                        "<div class='row'>",
                                            "<div class = 'col-sm-3 col-md-3'><label class='control-label'>Request Log Date: </label></div>",
                                            "<div class = 'col-sm-3 col-md-3'>{{Ctrl}}</div>",
                                            "<div class = 'col-sm-3 col-md-3'><label class='control-label'>Number of Requests <em style='color:red'>*</em>: </label></div>",
                                            "<div class = 'col-sm-3 col-md-3'>{{Ctrl}}</div>",
                                        "</div></div>");
```

How to create a structure with 4 columns?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With Bootstrap V3, you may use Inline forms as follow :

```
var formTable = "".concat("<form class='form-inline'><h2>Raise a New Request</h2><hr/>",
                                  "<br/>",
                                    "<div class='form-group'>",
                                        "<div class = 'form-group'><label class='control-label'>Request Log Date: </label></div>",
                                        "<div class = 'form-group'>{{Ctrl}}</div>",
                                        "<div class = 'form-group'><label class='control-label'>Number of Requests <em style='color:red'>*</em>: </label></div>",
                                        "<div class = 'form-group'>{{Ctrl}}</div>",
                                    "</div></form>");
```

Here are more detail about this feature : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

Comment: Tried that. same isue. The data is shown as : Label  below that control , below that label, below that control.  What I want is the layout horizontally.

Comment: I have used the references of - bootstrap-responsive.min.css, bootstrap.min.css,
bootstrap.min.js